# Drive my approach to

Tags: word-difference

I read a sentence:

> The overarching principles that **drive my approach to** everything are laid out in Life Principles. In this section, I explain my principles in greater depth and show how they apply in the natural world, in our private lives and relationships, in business and policymaking, and of course at Bridgewater.

I understand 'Drive' is a metaphor here.
Could it be substitute with an alternative appropriate word?

Comment: It is being used as a synonym for **motivate** or **propel** or **govern**.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a metaphor.

The verb *to drive* has many meanings, one of which is:

> 16. To incite or impel powerfully or irresistibly; to force, compel (to or into some action, to do something; also, from a course of
>       action, etc.).

Source: OED(dot)com

The verb has quite a lengthy entry in the OED with at least 27 distinct meanings listed. Sadly, this doesn't help learners much. Just quite how a verb ends up with so many meanings is a bit of a mystery. In this case, this particular meaning has existed for a very long time, since at least the 12th century according to the attestations given in the OED in that particular entry.

In your example, I think it could be expressed like this: the principles *are responsible for compelling* the approach.

Comment: Agreed, good answer.  Unfortunately some words like "drive" or "run" have many, many meanings, not all of which are related to each other.